# When should I create my Sqlite database in my app?

Tags: android, sqlite, xamarin.android, xamarin

When my application starts for the first time it needs to create the database it'll be using. I don't know at what point I should be creating the database if it doesn't already exist yet, and I don't know how to ensure I don't try to create the database if it already does exist. Currently, the following works, where I execute `CreateTable` when the first activity in my app runs:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
    base.OnCreate(bundle);
    base.SetContentView(Resource.Layout.SiteListLayout);

    DataManager.CreateTable<Site>();
    DataManager.CreateTable<PanelLog>();
    DataManager.CreateTable<Trace>();
}
```

Basically, this works because the `CreateTable` method checks to see if the table already exists before creating it. However, I don't like the idea of frivolously running some code knowing it's going to fail because of some of some exception to its expectations. I'd prefer to be more explicit.

Therefore, how can I execute code the first time my app runs to test if the tables need to be created, and if so to create them? And any subsequent time my app runs it doesn't check that code.

Comment: [Use SQLiteOpenHelper](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db).

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use to create or upgrade my database, and it seems to work really well. It's a hack from various sources in the web. It creates 4 tables, unless they already exist. I haven't included the static variables but that should be clear enough to follow?

```
private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
        db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE_2);
        db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE_3);
        db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE_LIST_SUB);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE_2);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE_3);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_LIST_SUB);
        onCreate(db);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create your database at the main_activity if you want, you can even create it on the splash screen activity if you have one.

As long you don't change the tables names, they will be created only one time, which is the first time the class that contains create table commands is called.

**UPDATE**

Check this [Website](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html), there you ll find a very simle tutorial, a bit long but very helful, if you don't have time you can try to use the code for creating your tables.

Answer (score 0):

You can use other data storage options in android.take a look at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal.You may find any storage option that are specific and secure to be used by a single app and their lifetime will be until you uninstall the app.So store in it the information either you created database or not,and check that storage everytime you run that app.